# Applying Fundamental theorem of calculus

Tags: calculus

Following a book I found this line

$f(y) - f(x) = \int_x^y f'(t) dt$   by Fundamental Theorem of Calculus

Can someone explain how the theorem have been applied?
I remember that Fundamental theorem of calculus is:

$F'(x) = {d\over dx} \int_c^x f(t) dt = f(x)$

but can not find the way of applying as above.

Comment: I believe you mean $F'(x) = \frac{d}{dx} \int_c^x f(t) \,dt = \cdots$.

Comment: yeah you are right. Now it is edited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fundamental theorem states the following:

If $f$ is a continuous function, then the function $F(x) = \int_a^x f(t) \; dt$ is differentiable with $F'(x)= f(x)$.

Now we apply this to calculate $F(x) = \int _a^x f'(t) \; dt$. The fundamental theorem states that $F'(x) = f'(x)$, i.e. the derivative of $F - f$ is zero. By the mean value theorem this implies that $F - f$ is constant, so we know $F(x) = f(x) + c$ for some constant $c$. Plugging in $x = a$ yields $0 = F(a) = f(a) + c$, which implies $\int_a^x f'(t) \; dt = F(x) = f(x) - f(a)$.

Comment: Thanks! This is the explanation i was looking for

Answer (score 0):

Some definitions are in order:

$\frac{d}{dt} f(t)=f'(t)$

You must know that:

$\int f'(t) dt=f(t)+Constant$

Now the limited integral between $x$ and $y$ can be written as:

$\int_x^y f'(t) dt = f(t)\Big|_x^y = f(y)+Constant - (f(x)+Constant) = f(y)-f(x)$

What you state in the question : $\int_c^x f(t) dt = f(x)$ is **not correct**

Some texts use this notation:

$\frac{d}{dt} F(t)=F'(t)=f(t)$

According to the above notation, we get:

$\int_x^y f(t) dt =F(y)-F(x)$

This is an example of the above notation: 
[FundamentalTheoremsofCalculus](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FundamentalTheoremsofCalculus.html).